# Why is my dog always behind me?

Tags: dogs, behavior

Why does my dog always sit BEHIND me? His bed is about 3 feet (90 cm) away diagonally from my gliding chair, but he will always sit behind my glider. If I leave the room, he will sit in his bed or just follow me around and ALWAYS BEHIND me?

Comment: my dog is like that. Does he cry if you go out without him, or have any other symptoms?

Comment: I think that dogs tend to sit behind the leaders of the pack. So most probably your dog considers you the leader of the pack and sits behind you for that reason.

Comment: Consider yourself a lucky guy, it took me month of intense training to teach my dog to walk (at least technically) behind me. It shows that your dog accepts you as his pack leader. Enjoy it. In terms of laying behind your glider chair, it's because it's the closest he can get to you when you're sitting on your desk. Mainly because he loves you and wants to be close to you. The only way changing this is to constantly send him back to his bed until he gets the message.

Comment: My dog is a bit insecure and he always wants me in his vision for reassurance.

Answer (score 1):

Your dog will always be around you (behind, in front, next to) because he feels safe around you and he knows you are the pack leader. They have bonded with you and this is a really good thing. They trust you and want to be near you 24/7. However, this can also lead to some attachment issues, so if you want them to be more independent and apart from you from time to time, try to use a dog gate in front of your room door to block you from him but still be in sight, and give him a treat. Then a few days later, have him be a little more apart from you, and give him a treat if he stays. This will behaviorally train your dog want to be apart from you sometimes and still feel safe when you are not around.